# Error thrown when trying to display GIF in html template

Tags: html, angularjs, error-handling, gif

*ERROR MESSAGE:* **Module parse failed: C:\src\imgs\giphy.gif Unexpected character '�' (1:6)**

**You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '�' (1:6)**

Trying to display a GIF inside a md-tabs inside of an md-dialog. PNG's load fine. Not sure what the issue is.

template.html:

```
<md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-swipe-content md-align-tabs="bottom" md-center-tabs class="feature-tabs" md-no-ink-bar>

            <md-tab label="1">
                <!--<md-tab-label>
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="../../../imgs/format-icon-audio.svg"></md-icon>
                </md-tab-label>-->
                <md-content class="md-padding">
                <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab One</h1>
                <p> More intuitive. More responsive. </p>
                <img src="../../../imgs/giphy.gif">
                <!--<img src='../../../../app/images/mini-balls2.gif'>-->
                <!--<img src="../../../imgs/logo@2x.png" alt="Splash Gif" style="width:400px;height:127px;">-->
                </md-content>
            </md-tab>
```

webpack-common.config.js:

```
{
    test: /.(gif|png|woff(2)?|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=\.]+)?$/,
    // https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils
    loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&name=./assets/[name].[hash:6].[ext]'
}
```

[ERROR SCREEN CAPTURE WHEN BUILT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iuvf.png)

Comment: Have you checked your GIF is not corrupted? By opening it in an image editor for example.

Comment: @R.Saban yes I cracked it open with a hex editor. Used wikipedias file format descriptor as a guide and the header matched. 
(hex)               value     Meaning
0:     47 49 46
       38 39 61     GIF89a    Header

Comment: I also tried giving the <img> tag more info such as "alt = ..." and width and height attributes that match the gif; still no luck

Comment: I added a screenshot of the error for ref.

Comment: I see '../../../' in the path, have you checked you are not mixing up local path with web_root path?

Comment: Please quote the error message inside the question, instead of just embedding it as a picture. From the error message it sounds like it tries to parse the GIF as some kind of data/script that follows a certain syntax. It explicitly says, _"You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type"_ - have you looked into that?

Comment: <!--<img src="../../../imgs/logo@2x.png" alt="Splash Gif" style="width:400px;height:127px;">--> loads correctly and it lives in the same directory as the gif.

Comment: @CBroe attempting to use web-pack to load it, not sure if that is the correct method. In theory HTML can load gif's natively with <img> tags without using an outside loader, but I see external loaders like webpack being used with larger web apps.

Answer (score 1):

**RESOLVED:** Issue was webpack only handling lower case extensions. To Windows *.gif == .GIF* but webpacks loader is case sensitive. Same issue with *.png vs .PNG*. I used a **Regex** to force the extension to lowercase and all is good in the neighborhood.